# How to change DataGridRow Foreground when IsMouseOver= true?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, ismouseover

i m facing one problem in my application that in datagridrow's IsMouseOver= true property changes background color but i m not able to change foreground..
To check property i have used trigger..
can anyone help me to solve it..

Comment: IsMouseOver requires a postback to the server... you could wrap in an ASP update panel, or, it might be easier to use CSS:Hover

Comment: @Rexxo He asked on WPF not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `DataGridRow` Foreground color when mouse is over, you have to use style trigger. This is an example of how to do it. In this example I set the `Foreground` color to white to make it more visible.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="PocWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="GreenForegroundStyle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="True" RowStyle="{StaticResource GreenForegroundStyle}">

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```
namespace PocWpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();

            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");

            this.dgTest.ItemsSource = list;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the result:**
[image]

Comment: its not working and instend of "Foreground" ,"Background " is working fine for me...

Comment: I updated my answer to include XAML, code-behind and the result on my machine. Hope this help!

Comment: hey thnx for kind help .this works for me fine...but Result is somewhat strange that when i have used key then its works but when i just used target type then its not working for all datagridRow as my style is in Resource dictionary ... by the at this works...

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> 
    <Style.Triggers> 
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger> 
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: But i m working on desktop application with wpf@Rexxo and according to ur answer its not working..@Miklós Balogh